# Magento and configurable product attributes

Tags: php, magento

I have an issue with displaying product custom attributes.
I've read every resources through google but still no success.
The problem is that I have to show size attribute of configurable product on category grid and list view.
Every solution on google suggested something like

```
$_product->getAttributeText('size')
```

but I ended up at just a single string - "S" or "M" instead of an array.
How can I fetch all possible sizes of all simple products which belongs to particular configurable product without much hassle?

**UPDATE**

After using solution proposed by Joseph Mastey I encountered another problem. I managed to show all possible options for given attribute, but now I need to show only these options which are available to buy. For example if t-shirt size L is out of stock or is disabled, L option should not be shown. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Were you ever able to come up with a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When dealing with configurable products (or any time you're dealing with a concept for only one type of product, as configurable attributes are), you'll probably be working with `getTypeInstance`. See below, I grab the configurable attributes for the product, then find the one for size. You could also just run through every configurable attribute if you wanted. Or if size is the only configurable attribute, just skip that `if()`.

```
$attrs  = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
foreach($attrs as $attr) {
    if(0 == strcmp("size", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
        $options    = $attr['values'];
        foreach($options as $option) {
            print "{$option['store_label']}<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps! Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. There was only one simple issue, getConfigurableAttributesAsArray had to be called with $_product parameter.